# Kendo UI: How to bind Kendo UI hierarchical datagrid detailInit event using MVVM (data-attribute)

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm, kendo-template

I am constructing a hierarchical datagrid using Kendo UI and I am using MVVM methodology for widget binding.
Here is the **[DEMO](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy)** of the kind of hierarchical grid I want to make. But the example here uses jQuery and not MVVM.

How can I bind the [`detailInit`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-detailInit) event to my `viewModel` using `data` attributes using `MVVM`?

I want to bind the event using the below code but it is not working:

**JS:**

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    ......
    ..........
    dataGridDetailInit: function (e) {
        //Here I want to catch the detailInit event of the dataGrid
    },
    ..........
    ......
});
```

**HTML (Kendo template):**

```
<!-- Datagrid -->
<div data-role="grid" 
    data-columns="[
        {'field':'FullName', 'title':'Full Name'},
        {'field':'Email', 'title':'Email'},
        {'field':'HomeTel', 'title':'HomeTel'},
        {'field':'Mobile', 'title':'MobileTel'},
        {'field':'Contact_Type', 'title':'Contact Type'},

    ]" 
    data-bind ="source: address_book_datagrid_observable.datasource,
                events: { 
                    detailInit: dataGridDetailInit 
                }" 
    data-pageable='{
                    refresh: false,
                    pageSizes: true,
                    buttonCount: 5,
                }'
    data-navigatable = "true"
    data-resizable = "true"
    data-no-records= "true"
    data-messages = '{
        noRecords: "There is no data to be displayed"
    }'
    >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so while researching I came across [this link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-can-i-declare-a-hierarchical-grid-using-mvvm).

On this issue, an engineer from Telerik asserted this:

> All Kendo widgets can be configured via [data attributes](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/markup). Building a
>   hierarchical grid declaratively is supported too, however please have
>   in mind that: detailInit event should not be bound through the events
>   binding but via data-attribute.

**[Here is the example](http://jsbin.com/egeviw/2/edit?html,output)** of how the event binding could be accomplished.

The right way to bind `detailInit` event to `viewModel` using `MVVM` (data attibute is) using `data-detail-init` as below:

```
<!-- Datagrid -->
<div data-role="grid" 
    data-columns="[
        {'field':'FullName', 'title':'Full Name'},
        {'field':'Email', 'title':'Email'},
        {'field':'HomeTel', 'title':'HomeTel'},
        {'field':'Mobile', 'title':'MobileTel'},
        {'field':'Contact_Type', 'title':'Contact Type'},

    ]" 
    data-bind ="source: viewModel.datasource" 
    data-detail-init="viewModel.dataGridDetailInit"
    data-pageable='{
                    refresh: false,
                    pageSizes: true,
                    buttonCount: 5,
                }'
    data-navigatable = "true"
    data-resizable = "true"
    data-no-records= "true"
    data-messages = '{
        noRecords: "There is no data to be displayed"
    }'
    >
</div>
```